# Подскажите алгоритм решения задачи, необходимо из текста вернуть счёт матча

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию, которая будет возвращать счёт из текста. Числа в тексте могут быть от нуля до девяти. Важно вернуть цифры в правильном порядке.

Пример:

- "new score: two three" - вернуть "2 : 3".
- "two two" - вернуть "2 : 2".
- "Arsenal just conceded another goal, two nil" - вернуть "2 : 0".

Пробовал через метод строк `str.includes`, но не могу сообразить, как сохранить порядок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм очевиден: ищем слова в строке ➝ заменяем их числами ➝ выводим.

```js
const dict = ['nil', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']; 
const wordsRe = new RegExp(dict.join('|'), 'gi'); 

const foo = str => (str.match(wordsRe) || [])
  .map(word => dict.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()))
  .join(' : '); 

console.log(foo('new score: two three')); 
console.log(foo('two two')); 
console.log(foo('Arsenal just conceded another goal, two nil'));
```

Метод `includes` выполняет **проверку вхождения** подстроки в строку, а не поиск подстрок (как `indexOf`/`match`).